# Magento2 - how to show custom menu in top menu?

Tags: magento2, navigation, topmenu

I need to show only first level categories and their products on top menu to replace Magento's default top menu.

For example categories and products should display like:

> Tshirts 
>    Polo Tshirts  Price:$10.00 
>    Polo Tshirts Green  Price:$10.00
>    Polo Tshirts Yellow Price:$10.00
>
> Shirts 
>    Polo shirts  Price:$10.00
>    Polo Tshirts Green  Price:$10.00 
>    Polo Tshirts Yellow Price:$10.00

How to get the product collection in topmenu blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

1) Menu content in M2 is generated from Block - `vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Topmenu.php`

2) To make changes in HTML structure, we need to override the Block in our custom Package Module say `app/code/Mypackage/Mymodule/Block/Html/Topmenu.php`

3) Sample code to override

```
namespace Mypackage\Mymodule\Block\Html;

class Topmenu extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu

{

// your code to get first level categories

}
```

4) Override above file through `app/code/Mypackage/Mymodule/etc/di.xml`

5) Make desired changes in the HTML of Menu and css as needed.